# Is there a MemoryStream that accepts a Span<T> or Memory<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm reading data from many sources (MemoryMappedFiles or FileStream). One problem is though that every single call to read a byte, int or some other type is extremely slow. So I'd like to read a chunk of data into an array and hand this over to a lightweight memory stream and do the reading of the individual components there.

The problem is that the current MemorySrream of .NET does only allow an array in the constructor, but I would need a Stream that is able to handle Span or Memor for example. There is a ReadOnlyMemoryStream as an internal class deeply buried in the .NET source code.

The interesting thing is though that the ReadOnlyMemoryStream is slower than the MemoryStream where I would have thought it shouldn't make a big difference.

Is there any better implementation?

Comment: `Span<T>` cannot work as this is stack-only and cannot be part of a heap-allocated class like `MemoryStream`. It should be possibe to create a Stream on  `Memory<T>`, but I'm not aware of such an implementation.

Comment: @KlausGütter: Of course you are right. It seems that I need to cerate my own classes one as a ref struct and one a a regular struct or class so that I can use Span<T> or Memory<T>. The only available class but internal in the .NET Core source class that I know is ReadOnlyMemoryStream that accepts an Memory<T>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is such an extension method, provided by `Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance` package

- see [Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance.Extensions Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.highperformance.extensions?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-6.1) for the doc
- code can be found at [code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/b2f8fcb4660a8c16ecb076a182b1218d3648e447/Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance/Streams/MemoryStream.cs#L26)

Comment: Thx for the info. I knew about the Toolkit, but I haven't had a look at the extension methods.

Comment: That's an internal class, though. If you're using the NuGet package, you've got no easy way to access that.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `Span`, you're already as fast as it gets, just read straight through it instead of plopping a stream on top of it.

A `Span` even gives you access to really nifty things like straight `struct` mapping without copies (`MemoryMarshal.Cast`), span increments (the equivalent to a stream advancing, part of `Unsafe.Add`), block copies if actually necessary (`Unsafe.Copy`) etc.

Comment: Of course but the Stream offers additional methods (e.g. with the binaryreader). I wrote my own extension methods. You are of course right doing it directly, but still the question is why is the MemoryStream faster than ReadOnlyMemoryStream (which uses Span).

Comment: If that's the question, then you put the wrong title to your post. As to `BinaryReader`, all its methods are also part of `Marshal` and `MemoryMarshal` and available on raw `Spans` as well.

Comment: @msedi I assume it's caused by GC pinning. Span is stack-only, so it shouldn't be possible to store it in an managed object, I couldn't find the ``ReadOnlyMemoryStream`` class you mentioned, but I assume it either copy the data to a managed array or pin the underlying memory with GCHandle, which is slow and can potentially cause other performance issues later. There's a closed PR that tried to add something similar https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/84103

Answer (score 1):

Once again, late to the party but: you can wrap a `Memory<T>` with a stream, so long as you're happy to use unsafe code.

The class you want is [`UnmanagedMemoryStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream?view=net-6.0), and it is supported by all current versions of dotnet. You can use it like this:

```cs
var m = new Memory<int>(new int[100]);

unsafe
{
    using var p = m.Pin();
    using var s = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(
        (byte*)p.Pointer, m.Length, m.Length, FileAccess.Write);
    using var w = new BinaryWriter(s);
    w.Write(123);
}

Debug.Assert(m.Span[0] == 123);
```

(`UnmanagedMemoryStream`s are read-only unless you specifically request write-access)

This approach works with anything you can get a pointer to, which includes `Span<T>`. I've done no profiling on performance of this flavour of stream compared to a regular `MemoryStream`.

---

As an alternative approach that doesn't use unsafe code, I've done things like use `ArrayPool` to provide plain byte arrays on demand for reading stuff into from various places, and then wrapped those pools in memorystreams, spans or memories as necessary. This can be *slightly* faster than using `Memory` as your base buffer type because there's one less layer of abstraction, though it isn't quite as tidy to use (requiring `finally` rather than `using` to guarantee return to the pool, for example). This may not be practical in your specific situation, but it isn't a bad architecture to use for future work if you're not too constrained by the need to use `Memory`.