# Generate memory stream from String object using efficient fashion (ReadOnlyMemory/Span)

Tags: c#, string, memory-management, stream

As far as I know, there is two main ways for converting a `string` into `MemoryStream.`

1. `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents));`
2. `UnmanagedMemoryStream ums = UnmanagedMemoryStream(p.ToPointer(), 100);` or `Marshal.Copy(p , buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` which is the same as #2

Instead of copying `string` into `byte[]` and then creating a `MemoryStream` from it,  **I'm wondering to know if there is a nice workaround using `ReadOnlyMemory<>` and/or `Span<>` to create a `MemoryStream`** to gain more performant/efficient code (with zero GC operation and instant assignment)?

I know that `"someStringContentFoo".AsMemory()` yields a `ReadOnlyMemory<Char>`, but I just cannot convert it to a `MemoryStream`.
Moreover, there is a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance) which converts `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` to `MemoryStream` using `AsStream()` Extension Method, but I cannot convert `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` to `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` without using `ToArray()` which sacrifices memory and GC.

Brief: Is there a way to convert `string` to `MemoryStream` without paying *memory copy* penalty?

Comment: 1 and 2 are not equivalent: 1 uses UTF-8 encoding, 2 uses the internal representation of System.String, which happens to be UTF-16

Comment: Sorry for miss understanding. I mean `UnmanagedMemoryStream ums =...` and `Marshal.Copy(...` are equivalent. I've never mentioned anything like `#1`, I said `#2`. As a whole picture, I'm not going to focus on similarity or different of the two first approaches. Please attention to the Memory<>/Span<> thing instead.

Comment: Why does it need to be a `MemoryStream` and not another `Stream`-derived class?

Comment: @KlausGütter No reason. Please go ahead and tell me if you can convert it into other forms of stream without `MemoryStream` interfere.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636836/is-there-a-memorystream-that-accepts-a-spant-or-memoryt

Comment: [Nerdbank.Streams](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.Streams) has a [`ReadOnlySequence<byte>.AsStream()` extension method](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.Streams/blob/master/doc/AsStream.md#readonlysequencebyte) based on a [ReadOnlySequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.buffers.readonlysequence-1) which can itself be constructed from [ReadOnlyMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.readonlymemory-1).