# How to get MemoryStream (or another Stream) from Memory<byte> without reallocating?

Tags: c#

Is there an existing way get a `MemoryStream` (or another Stream) from `Memory<byte>` without reallocating?

Comment: You could inherit your own Stream implementation that wraps a `Memory<byte>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636836/is-there-a-memorystream-that-accepts-a-spant-or-memoryt

Comment: @HansPassant ty, i just finished to implement it but now i guess i had to delete.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the reference... new toys :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you construct a `MemoryStream` from a `byte[]` the [array is assigned as the stream's buffer](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs#L63-L74). In this case there is no additional allocation or copy.

Unfortunately there's no constructor that takes `Memory<byte>`. You'll have to call `Memory<byte>.ToArray()` to get there, and that *does* allocate. The documentation comment for `Memory<T>.ToArray()` states:

> Copies the contents from the memory into a new array.  This heap allocates, so should generally be avoided, however it is sometimes necessary to bridge the gap with APIs written in terms of arrays.

(Internally this is implemented via [`Span<T>.ToArray()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Span.cs#L469-L477).)

The `Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance` package adds an `AsStream()` extension that creates a thin stream wrapper around `Memory<byte>`, allowing you to read/write to your `Memory<byte>` without allocations.